# Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, drop-duplicates

The pandas `drop_duplicates` function is great for "uniquifying" a dataframe. I would like to drop all rows which are duplicates across a subset of columns. Is this possible?

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 0   A
1   foo 1   A
2   foo 1   B
3   bar 1   A
```

As an example, I would like to drop rows which match on columns `A` and `C` so this should drop rows 0 and 1.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

This is much easier in pandas now with [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and the keep parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'C'], keep=False)
```

Answer (score 121):

Just want to add to Ben's answer on [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

`keep` : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’

- first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
- last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
- **False : Drop all duplicates.**

So setting `keep` to False will give you desired answer.

> DataFrame.drop_duplicates(*args, **kwargs) Return DataFrame with
>   duplicate rows removed, optionally only considering certain columns
>
> Parameters:    subset : column label or sequence of labels, optional
>   Only consider certain columns for identifying duplicates, by default
>   use all of the columns keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default
>   ‘first’ first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence. last
>   : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence. False : Drop all
>   duplicates. take_last : deprecated inplace : boolean, default False
>   Whether to drop duplicates in place or to return a copy cols : kwargs
>   only argument of subset [deprecated] Returns:  deduplicated :
>   DataFrame

Answer (score 67):

If you want result to be stored in another dataset:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

or

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)
```

If same dataset needs to be updated:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Above examples will remove all duplicates and keep one, similar to `DISTINCT *` in SQL

Answer (score 16):

use `groupby` and `filter`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})
df.groupby(["A", "C"]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] == 1)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Try these various things**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar","foo"], "B":[0,1,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A","A"]})

>>>df.drop_duplicates( "A" , keep='first')
```

or

```
>>>df.drop_duplicates( keep='first')
```

or

```
>>>df.drop_duplicates( keep='last')
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually, drop rows 0 and 1 only requires (any observations containing matched A and C is kept.):

```
In [335]:

df['AC']=df.A+df.C
In [336]:

print df.drop_duplicates('C', take_last=True) #this dataset is a special case, in general, one may need to first drop_duplicates by 'c' and then by 'a'.
     A  B  C    AC
2  foo  1  B  fooB
3  bar  1  A  barA

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

But I suspect what you really want is this (one observation containing matched A and C is kept.):

```
In [337]:

print df.drop_duplicates('AC')
     A  B  C    AC
0  foo  0  A  fooA
2  foo  1  B  fooB
3  bar  1  A  barA

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

## Edit:

Now it is much clearer, therefore:

```
In [352]:
DG=df.groupby(['A', 'C'])   
print pd.concat([DG.get_group(item) for item, value in DG.groups.items() if len(value)==1])
     A  B  C
2  foo  1  B
3  bar  1  A

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: If that was what I wanted, I'd just use `df.drop_duplicates(['A','C'])` as the default keeps one observation take the first or last as I mentioned in the question - although I've just realised I had the keyword wrong as I was writing from memory. What I want is to drop all rows which are identical on the columns of interest (A and C in the example data).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated()` to flag all duplicates and filter out flagged rows. If you need to assign columns to `new_df` later, make sure to call `.copy()` so that you don't get `SettingWithCopyWarning` later on.

```py
new_df = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['A', 'C'], keep=False)].copy()
```

[image: res1]

One nice feature of this method is that you can conditionally drop duplicates with it. For example, to drop all duplicated rows only if column A is equal to `'foo'`, you can use the following code.

```py
new_df = df[~( df.duplicated(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'], keep=False) & df['A'].eq('foo') )].copy()
```

[image: res2]

Also, if you don't wish to write out columns by name, you can pass slices of `df.columns` to `subset=`. This is also true for `drop_duplicates()` as well.

```py
# to consider all columns for identifying duplicates
df[~df.duplicated(subset=df.columns, keep=False)].copy()

# the same is true for drop_duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns, keep=False)

# to consider columns in positions 0 and 2 (i.e. 'A' and 'C') for identifying duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[[0, 2]], keep=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check 2 columns with try and except statements, this one can help out.

```
if "column_2" in df.columns:
    try:
        df[['column_1', "column_2"]] = df[['header', "column_2"]].drop_duplicates(subset = ["column_2", "column_1"] ,keep="first")
    except:
        df[["column_2"]] = df[["column_2"]].drop_duplicates(subset="column_2" ,keep="first")
        print(f"No column_1 for {path}.")
try:
    df[["column_1"]] = df[["column_1"]].drop_duplicates(subset="column_1" ,keep="first")
except:
    print(f"No column_1 or column_2 for {path}.")
```