# Pandas dataframe .stack() "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a multiindexed (3 column levels) pandas. Dataframe which is something like this:

```
       t1                      t2
       p1          p2          p1          p2
       v1    v2    v1    v2    v1    v2    v1    v2

       A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
```

I need to rearrange it to:

```
       t1         t2
       v1   v2    v1    v2

 p1    A    B     E     F
 p2    C    D     G     H
```

But when I try:

> df.stack(level=1)

I get:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

[This implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242735/1318135) that the repetition of labels makes this operation impossible, but that doesn't make sense to me, because otherwise there would be no reason to run .stack().

1. Why do I get this error? I imagine I'm not understanding the linked answer.
2. How can I achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Why not use `pivot`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html ?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? And can you provide a reproducible example? If I try to replicate this with `df = pd.DataFrame([list('ABCDEFGH')], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['t1','t2'],['p1','p2'],['v1','v2']]))`, then it works fine for me.