# Python/Pandas, .count not working on larger data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of True/False values in a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [True, False, True],
                  'b': [True, True, True],
                  'c': [False, False, True]})
count_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['count'] = df[df[count_cols] == True].count(axis=1)
```

[image]

This is working fine on this example. But when I test it on my actual df (shape - (25168, 303)), I am getting the following error:

I Understood from - [What does `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean) - that this usually occurs when there are duplicate values in the index and I have tried both `df.reindex()` and `df[~df.index.duplicated()]`, but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: have you tried  `df.sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that throws the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter columns by list and count `True`s values by `sum` - `True`s are processing like `1`s:

```
df['count'] = df[count_cols].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
       a     b      c  count
0   True  True  False      2
1  False  True  False      1
2   True  True   True      3
```

EDIT: For avoid error one possible solution is convert values to numpy array:

```
df['count'] = np.sum(df[count_cols].values, axis=1)
print (df)
       a     b      c  count
0   True  True  False      2
1  False  True  False      1
2   True  True   True      3
```

Comment: Thanks, but `df[count_cols].sum(axis=1)` throws the same error

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you have any idea why mine works on the test df but not the big one?

Comment: @Maverick It seems some data related issue, hard to know