# Pandas `groupby.aggregate` on `df.index.duplicated()`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

Scenario. Assume a

1. `pd.DataFrame`, loaded from an external source
2. where one row is a line from a sensor. The index is a `DateTimeIndex`
3. with some rows having `df.index.duplicated()==True`. This actually means, there are lines with the same timestamp from different sensors.

Now applying some logic, like `df.loc[df.A>0, 'my_col'] = 1`, I ran into [ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean). This can be solved by simply **removing the duplicated rows** using

`df[~df.index.duplicated()]`

But I wonder, if it would be possible, to actually **apply a column based function during the Index de-duplication process**? E.g.: Calculating the `mean/max/min` of column `A/B/C` for the duplicated rows.

Is this possible? Its something like a **`groupby.aggregate` on `df.index.duplicated()`** rows.

Comment: have you tried something like `df.groupby(df.index).mean()`?

Comment: or `df.groupby(level=0).mean()`?

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. 

That would in fact apply the `mean()` function on **all** columns, not only specific ones. E.g: If I would like to hold the `max` value on column `A` and the `mean` value for column `B`, that would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `describe`

```
df.groupby(level=0).describe()
```