# mssql server database inserting more rows than expected in pandas iterrows odbc driver ubuntu machine

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

```
print(f"df_shape {df.shape}")
 (3497, 39)
```

But, I see row above 30 thousand getting imported in to database.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_A(Sno,A,B) \
     values(?,?,?,)', \
         row.Sno, row.A, row.B)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approached solved the issue,
`df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated()]`

[Pandas `groupby.aggregate` on `df.index.duplicated()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162231/pandas-groupby-aggregate-on-df-index-duplicated)
[duplicate removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162231/pandas-groupby-aggregate-on-df-index-duplicated)  [Pandas concat: ValueError: Shape of passed values is blah, indices imply blah2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2/53663132#53663132)