# Getting reindex from a duplicate axis error in the following query from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a query (countries who received a gold medal) from the data frame and store into elsewhere. A portion of the dataset is shown below.

[image: A portion of the dataset]

This is the query I have run

```py
only_gold = df.where(df['Gold'] > 0)
only_gold.head()
```

[image: Here is the error generated]

I have also tried the query

```py
only_gold = df[df['Gold'] > 0]
only_gold.head()
```

But the same error has been generated

Comment: You have a duplicate names of ```Gold``` in your data. Does this answer your question? [What does \`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis\` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean)

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when multiple columns have the same name. As I pointed out in the comment, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean) should answer your questions. One way of dealing with it is to remove the duplicates by renaming your columns or by an answer from @tuomastik or [Parseltongue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799290/12281892):

```py
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

# or 
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

If your data is created by merging some other data frames (often the case), then use the `ignore_index=True` option.