# Preparing training model for neural network classification

Tags: python, split, pandas

thanks for your help! I'm having difficulties preparing my neural network classification.

When trying to fit my model, I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think I understand why it is. Here's the screenshot of the x_train variable:
[image: X_Train]

I think it would also be helpful to show you the df I'm pulling this from. I've done text_to_word_sequence and one_hot encoding on it. It looks like...
[image: df]

It seems to me that the rows need to be split but I'm not sure the best way to do that in a way that will allow the train to properly fit.

Thanks for your help again!

Comment: df.explode('codes') would split row wise. but from the look of your data, you still need more cleaning and processing. consider tokenising and clearing punctuations before before coding

Comment: Thanks for responding! So I tried that and it looked to reflect that in the output but when I went to do datadf.head(), it responded with the same thing. I then also tried saving it to a variable and got an error. 
"ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"
Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, i am assuming you reassigned the new result to a new variable.  and not reassigned it to a new column within the same dataframe... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean