# Getting "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis: " as I want to multiply specific columns bases on value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to multiply certain columns based on value of another column.

```
   merged.loc[merged.check.str.contains('1'), 'price'] = merged['price']*100000.0
   merged.head()
```

---

But I am getting this error.

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean)?

Comment: Yes. there are no duplicate indexes.

Comment: I basically want to multiple  *price* by 100000 if *check* contains 1

Comment: `merged.loc[merged.check.str.contains('1'), 'price'] *= 100000.0`