# How to resolve ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

**Input**

| Client | First name | Last Name | Start Date | End Date | Amount | Invoice Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | John | Kennedy | 15-01-2021 | 28-02-2021 | 137,586.00 | 20-04-2021 |
| YYY | Peter | Paul | 7-02-2021 | 31-03-2021 | 38,750.00 | 20-04-2021 |
| ZZZ | Michael | K | 10-03-2021 | 29-04-2021 | 137,586.00 | 30-04-2021 |

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_excel ('file.xlsx',parse_dates=['Start Date','End Date'] )
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')

df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'],x['End Date']), axis=1)
df = df.explode('r')
print(df)

months = df['r'].dt.month

starts, ends = months.ne(months.groupby(level=0).shift(1)), months.ne(months.groupby(level=0).shift(-1))


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': df['First name'],
           'Start Date': df.loc[starts, 'r'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                   'End Date': df.loc[ends, 'r'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                   'Date Diff': df.loc[ends, 'r'].dt.strftime('%d').astype(int)-df.loc[starts, 'r'].dt.strftime('%d').astype(int)+1})

df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(), :]

df2 = pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

df2['Amount'] = df['Amount'].mul(df2['Date_Diff'])
print(df['Amount'])
print (df)

df.to_excel('report.xlsx', index=True)
```

**Error**
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

**Expected output**

[image]

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis\` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some correction in your input Excel file, namely change *First name*
to *First Name* - with **capital** "N", just like in other columns.

Then, to read your Excel file, it is enough to run:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date',
   'Invoice Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

No need to call *to_datetime*.

Note also that since *Invoice Date* contains also dates, I added this column to *parse_dates*
list.

Then define two functions:

1. A function to get monthly data for the current row:

   ```
   def getMonthData(grp, amnt, dayNo):
       return pd.Series([grp.min(), grp.max(), amnt * grp.size / dayNo],
           index=['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Amount'])
   ```

   It converts the input Series of dates (for a single month) into the "new" content of
   the output rows (start / end dates and the proper share of the total amount, to be
   accounted for this month).

   It will be called in the following function.
2. A function to "explode" the current row:

   ```
   def rowExpl(row):
       ind = pd.date_range(row['Start Date'], row['End Date']).to_series()
       rv = ind.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(getMonthData,
           amnt=row.Amount, dayNo=ind.size).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
       rv.insert(0, 'Client', row.Client)
       rv.insert(1, 'First Name', row['First Name'])
       rv.insert(2, 'Last Name', row['Last Name'])
       return rv.assign(**{'Invoice Date': row['Invoice Date']})
   ```

And the last step is to get the result. Apply *rowExpl* to each row and concatenate
the partial results into a single output DataFrame:

```
result = pd.concat(df.apply(rowExpl, axis=1).values, ignore_index=True)
```

The result, for your data sample is:

```
  Client First Name Last Name Start Date   End Date   Amount Invoice Date
0    XXX       John   Kennedy 2021-01-15 2021-01-31  51976.9   2021-04-20
1    XXX       John   Kennedy 2021-02-01 2021-02-28  85609.1   2021-04-20
2    YYY      Peter      Paul 2021-02-07 2021-02-28  16084.9   2021-04-20
3    YYY      Peter      Paul 2021-03-01 2021-03-31  22665.1   2021-04-20
4    ZZZ    Michael         K 2021-03-10 2021-03-31  59350.8   2021-04-30
5    ZZZ    Michael         K 2021-04-01 2021-04-29  78235.2   2021-04-30
```

Don't be disaffected by seemingly too low precision of *Amount* column.
It is only the way how *Jupyter Notebook* displays the DataFrame.

When you run `result.iloc[0, 5]`, you will get:

```
51976.933333333334
```

with full, **actually** held precision.

Comment: VaIdi_Bo tried to execute the function , but output is blank

Comment: If you executed *result = pd.concat(…)* then the actual result is in *result* variable.
To see this result, execute e.g. *print(result)*. Check also the file name (whether this file actually contains the expected data).

Comment: Another check: Instead of reading from an Excel file, load the data from e.g. a CSV file, then exeute my code.