# ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels when adding EMAs via group_by

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock, pandas-ta

Sorry for the noob question.

I have a bunch of minute data like so:

```
                     timestamp    open  high     low   close  volume  trade_count      vwap symbol  volume_10_day
0       2021-06-28 11:15:00+00:00  1.8899  1.89  1.8899  1.8900    1200            2  1.889942   AADI       102027.6
1       2021-06-28 13:15:00+00:00  1.8200  1.82  1.8100  1.8100     710            8  1.818282   AADI       102027.6
2       2021-06-28 13:30:00+00:00  1.8600  1.87  1.8500  1.8600   13845           52  1.858409   AADI       102027.6
3       2021-06-28 13:35:00+00:00  1.8659  1.87  1.8626  1.8700     860            5  1.867670   AADI       102027.6
4       2021-06-28 13:40:00+00:00  1.8700  1.87  1.8477  1.8477    7386           33  1.859019   AADI       102027.6
...                           ...     ...   ...     ...     ...     ...          ...       ...    ...            ...
423069  2021-01-13 00:35:00+00:00  1.2600  1.27  1.2500  1.2600  242391          140  1.260218    ZOM       122065.8
423070  2021-01-13 00:40:00+00:00  1.2600  1.26  1.2500  1.2600  129074          108  1.256255    ZOM       122065.8
423071  2021-01-13 00:45:00+00:00  1.2500  1.26  1.2500  1.2500  297198          151  1.253695    ZOM       122065.8
423072  2021-01-13 00:50:00+00:00  1.2600  1.26  1.2500  1.2600  223822          121  1.256325    ZOM       122065.8
423073  2021-01-13 00:55:00+00:00  1.2600  1.26  1.2500  1.2600  378248          222  1.255110    ZOM       122065.8

[423074 rows x 10 columns]


timestamp   open    high    low close   volume  trade_count vwap    symbol  volume_10_day
2021-07-26 13:00:00+00:00   2.7799  2.78    2.68    2.7 182448  285 2.712106    SOS 6552.7
2021-07-26 13:05:00+00:00   2.7 2.71    2.68    2.69    46906   154 2.692083    SOS 6552.7
```

I am then grouping them by their symbols, and adding EMAs to them:

```
ema72 = lambda x: ta.ema(df.loc[x.index, "close"], 72) 
ema89 = lambda x: ta.ema(df.loc[x.index, "close"], 89) 
ema216 = lambda x: ta.ema(df.loc[x.index, "close"], 216) 
ema267 = lambda x: ta.ema(df.loc[x.index, "close"], 267) 
ema200 = lambda x: ta.ema(df.loc[x.index, "close"], 200) 

df["EMA72"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema72).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df["EMA89"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema89).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df["EMA216"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema216).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df["EMA267"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema267).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df["EMA200"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema200).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Which gives the error:

```
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I can add the 72 and 89 ema fine by doing:

```
df["EMA72"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema72).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df["EMA89"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema89).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Will result in:

```
                       timestamp    open    high   low  close  volume  trade_count      vwap symbol  volume_10_day     EMA72     EMA89
0       2021-07-06 13:30:00+00:00  1.7200  1.7300  1.71  1.730   23342           54  1.723628   AADI       102027.6       NaN       NaN
1       2021-07-06 13:35:00+00:00  1.7300  1.7300  1.72  1.720   13225           26  1.729698   AADI       102027.6       NaN       NaN
2       2021-07-06 13:40:00+00:00  1.7199  1.7199  1.71  1.715    1740           12  1.712175   AADI       102027.6       NaN       NaN
3       2021-07-06 13:45:00+00:00  1.7150  1.7177  1.71  1.710    1223            9  1.714411   AADI       102027.6       NaN       NaN
4       2021-07-06 13:50:00+00:00  1.7100  1.7100  1.71  1.710     900            1  1.710000   AADI       102027.6       NaN       NaN
...                           ...     ...     ...   ...    ...     ...          ...       ...    ...            ...       ...       ...
247074  2021-01-13 00:35:00+00:00  1.2600  1.2700  1.25  1.260  242391          140  1.260218    ZOM       122065.8  1.264493  1.258082
247075  2021-01-13 00:40:00+00:00  1.2600  1.2600  1.25  1.260  129074          108  1.256255    ZOM       122065.8  1.264370  1.258125
247076  2021-01-13 00:45:00+00:00  1.2500  1.2600  1.25  1.250  297198          151  1.253695    ZOM       122065.8  1.263976  1.257944
247077  2021-01-13 00:50:00+00:00  1.2600  1.2600  1.25  1.260  223822          121  1.256325    ZOM       122065.8  1.263867  1.257990
247078  2021-01-13 00:55:00+00:00  1.2600  1.2600  1.25  1.260  378248          222  1.255110    ZOM       122065.8  1.263761  1.258035

[247079 rows x 12 columns]
```

But doing this:

```
df["EMA72"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema72).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df["EMA89"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema89).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df["EMA216"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema216).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df["EMA267"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema267).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df["EMA200"] = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(ema200).reset_index(0,drop=True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Gives the error:

```
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

I have tried removing the duplicated timestamps for each symbol:

```
df = df.groupby(['symbol', 'timestamp'])
df = df.last().sort_index().reset_index()

247079 // before
233228 // after
```

But it still gives the same error

I thought it may be something to do with the functions but when I do this:

```
df["EMA200"] = df.groupby('symbol')['close'].rolling(200).mean()
```

The error persists

Comment: because index has duplicate values. you find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean)

Comment: I tried your first code with similar data. I was able to retrieve it without error. `import yfinance as yf;import pandas_ta as ta;stocks = ['TSLA', 'MSFT', 'NIO', 'AAPL', 'AMD', 'ADBE', 'ALGN', 'AMZN'];data = yf.download(stocks, start='2021-12-01', end='2022-12-20', interval='1h');df = data.stack(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'symbol'})`

Comment: Thanks r, it gives the error `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2` for me

Comment: I suck at Python, do you think it could be because some symbols have downloaded the data multiple times for the same time period?

Comment: Nah it isn't that, I have removed the duplicated timestamps for each symbol and the error still persists

Comment: I ran the commented code in my environment with pandas:1.4.4,pandas_ta:0.3.14b0.