# Grouping on selected columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has multiple location and the number of visits by week. I want to filter out the locations that did not have any visitors in the most recent week.

I have tried the following:

```
df_select = df.loc[(df['end_date'] == "3/17/2023") & (df['visits'] != 0)]
df_group = df.groupby(['id','name','lat', 'lng']).agg({'visits': ['count']})
```

When I try this I get the following error:
“ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis”

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391)

Answer (score 0):

One of the filtering columns in your df_select assignment (namely `end_date` or `visits`) is likely a duplicate column label. If you can somehow make these column labels unique, the problem should be solved.

Similar issues are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean).

This phenomenon can be illustrated by this short example:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({i:list(range(3)) for i in range(10,14)})
df_select = df.loc[(df[11] == 1) & (df[12] != 0)]
```

Input:

```
   10  11  12  13
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
```

Output:

```
   10  11  12  13
1   1   1   1   1
```

Now, here it is with a duplicate column label `12`:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({i:list(range(3)) for i in range(10,14)})
df.columns=[min(col, 12) for col in df.columns]
df_select = df.loc[(df[11] == 1) & (df[12] != 0)]
```

Input:

```
   10  11  12  12
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
```

Output:

```
...

ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```