# Remove duplicates from dataframe, based on two columns A,B, keeping row with max value in another column C

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe which contains duplicates values according to two columns (A and B):

```
A B C
1 2 1
1 2 4
2 7 1
3 4 0
3 4 8
```

I want to remove duplicates keeping the row with max value in column C. This would lead to:

```
A B C
1 2 4
2 7 1
3 4 8
```

I cannot figure out how to do that. Should I use `drop_duplicates()`, something else?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can do it using group by:

```
c_maxes = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.transform(max)
df = df.loc[df.C == c_maxes]
```

`c_maxes` is a `Series` of the maximum values of `C` in each group but which is of the same length and with the same index as `df`. If you haven't used `.transform` then printing `c_maxes` might be a good idea to see how it works.

Another approach using `drop_duplicates` would be

```
df.sort('C').drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], take_last=True)
```

Not sure which is more efficient but I guess the first approach as it doesn't involve sorting.

**EDIT:**
From `pandas 0.18` up the second solution would be

```
df.sort_values('C').drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep='last')
```

or, alternatively,

```
df.sort_values('C', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'])
```

In any case, the `groupby` solution seems to be significantly more performing:

```
%timeit -n 10 df.loc[df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.max == df.C]
10 loops, best of 3: 25.7 ms per loop

%timeit -n 10 df.sort_values('C').drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep='last')
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
```

Comment: don't forget to assign the new dataframe (in this case to df): `df.sort_values('C', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], inplace=True)`

Comment: Adding to @PV8 ' comment, don't use `inplace` at all in the expression as it will not give expected results, assignment is still needed as no inplace work is done. Its better to do operations explicitly to avoid surprises.

Comment: don't know what you are talking about, but the inplace command works in that case, check the answer to `drop_duplicates` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas

Comment: `take_last=True` is not working, use `keep='last'` instead as per docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Please see the comments in the EDIT section.

Comment: @PV8 If you want to use `inplace` here you would have to do it in two stages, first passed to `sort_values` and then to `drop_duplicates` since both return `None` when `inplace=True`. However, nothing in the question suggest we want to use `inplace` here and doing so loses. Your code will return `None` and will also not affect `df` since `.sort_values` returns a view or copy.

Answer (score 16):

I think groupby should work.

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).max()['C']
```

If you need a dataframe back you can chain the reset index call.

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).max()['C'].reset_index()
```

Comment: This will just return a Series of the max value of C in each group, indexed by 'A' and 'B'.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `drop_duplicates` as you wanted

```
# initialisation
d = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,2,3,3], 'B' : [2,2,7,4,4],  'C' : [1,4,1,0,8]})

d = d.sort_values("C", ascending=False)
d = d.drop_duplicates(["A","B"])
```

If it's important to get the same order

```
d = d.sort_index()
```