# Select pd.DataFrame rows with the biggest intersection in terms of values of Depth (specific columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
| Meth.name  |  Min| Max    |Layer| Global name |
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
|   DTS      | 2600| 3041.2 | AC1 |  DTS        |
|   GGK      | 1800| 3200.0 | AC1 |  DEN        |
|   DTP      | 700 | 3041.0 | AC2 |  DT         |
|   DS       | 700 | 3041.0 | AC3 |  CALI       |
|   PF1      | 2800| 3012.0 | AC3 |  CALI       |
|   PF2      | 3000| 3041.0 | AC4 |  CALI       |
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
```

We have to drop duplicated rows by "Global name" column but in specific way : we wants to choose the row, which will give the biggest intersection with range calculated using max value of column `"Min"` and min value if column `"Max"` **of non-duplicated rows**. 
In example above this range will be [2600.0; 3041.0], so we wants to leave only row with `['Meth.name] == 'DS'` and overall result should be like:

```
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
| Meth.name  |  Min| Max    |Layer| Global name |
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
|   DTS      | 2600| 3041.2 | AC1 |  DTS        |
|   GGK      | 1800| 3200.0 | AC1 |  DEN        |
|   DTP      | 700 | 3041.0 | AC2 |  DT         |
|   DS       | 700 | 3041.0 | AC3 |  CALI       |
+------------+-----+--------+-----+-------------+
```

This problem, of course, can be solved in several iterations (calculate interval based on non-duplicated rows and then iteratively select only those rows (from duplicated) that will give biggest intersection), but I'm trying to discover the most efficient approach
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide expected output things?

Comment: *min value of column "Max" of non-duplicated rows* - why not 2200.0?

Comment: Could you please also present what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Tserenjamts, added expected result

Comment: @PankajJoshi, added some ideas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python(pandas): removing duplicates based on two columns keeping row with max value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093829/pythonpandas-removing-duplicates-based-on-two-columns-keeping-row-with-max-va)

Comment: @Mayeulsgc yea, this script can help on a final steps of the way

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the lines is not important you can do the following :

```py
df['diff'] = df['Max']-df['Min']
df=df.sort_values(["Global_name","diff"],ascending=True)
df.drop_duplicates('Global_name',keep='last')
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32093829/4350650) question

Comment: yea, but we need calculate intersection because the bigger interval not means the bigger intersection.

Comment: Can you put an example of a case where the bigger intersection is not the bgger interval in your question pls, would be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
# Helper function
def calc_overlap(x):
    if min_of_max == max_of_min:
        return 0

    low = max(min_of_max, x.Min)
    high = min(max_of_min, x.Max)

    return high-low

dup_global_name = df.Global_name.value_counts()[df.Global_name.value_counts() > 1].index
dup_global_name = list(dup_global_name)

# Filter duplicates
df_dup = df[df.Global_name.isin(dup_global_name)]

# Add overlap column
df_dup['overlap'] = df_dup.apply(lambda x: calc_overlap(x), axis=1)

#Select max overlap
df_dup = df_dup.loc[df_dup.groupby('Global_name').overlap.idxmax()]

# Drop overlap col
df_dup.drop('overlap', axis=1, inplace=True)

#Concatinate with nonduplicate ones
pd.concat([df[~df.Global_name.isin(dup_global_name)], df_dup])
```

The desired output:
[image]

Comment: the code you attached is a pseudo i guess? if not :
what is in "dup_global_name variable"?

Comment: Apologies, mistake in copy pasting. Corrected it now.