# Dataframe- Remove similar rows related based on two columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have following dataset:
[image]

this dataset print correlation of two columns at left
if you look at the row number 3 and 42, you will find they are same. only column position is different. that does not affect correlation. I want to remove column 42. But this dataset has many these row of similar values. I need a general algorithm to remove these similar value and have only unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the correlation_value seems to be the same, the operation should be commutative, so whatever the value, you just have to focus on two first columns. Sort the tuple and remove duplicates

```
# You can probably replace 'sorted' by 'set'
key = df[['source_column', 'destination_column']] \
          .apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis='columns')

out = df.loc[~key.duplicated()]
```

```
>>> out
  source_column destination_column  correlation_Value
0             A                  B                  1
2             C                  E                  2
3             D                  F                  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a self [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).  Without a code example, it's hard to answer, but something like this maybe:

```
df.merge(df, left_on="source_column", right_on="destination_column")
```

You can follow that up with a call to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: this question might make it easy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093829/remove-duplicates-from-dataframe-based-on-two-columns-a-b-keeping-row-with-max. But the difference in my question and this is that in my dataframe rows are different but similar

Comment: @DijkstraAlgorithm instead of posting a screenshot, please post your data as text, and code for your approach. You cannot expect others to do the work for you.  See the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section "Help others reproduce the problem". Also, did you look at the documentation for `drop_duplicates` I pointed to?  It allows you to "ignore" certain columns.