# Remove one of duplicate value in two columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

I am working on google collaboratory and I have two column on panda dataframe which some of the rows has similar value

```
A   B
Syd Syd
Aus Del
Mir Ard
Dol Dol
```

I wish that the value in column B which has duplicate value with column A to be deleted, like below :

```
A   B
Syd 
Aus Del
Mir Ard
Dol
```

I try to use `drop_duplicates()` like this one [Remove duplicates from dataframe, based on two columns A,B, keeping row with max value in another column C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093829/remove-duplicates-from-dataframe-based-on-two-columns-a-b-keeping-row-with-max) but it will delete the entire column B. Any suggestions smarter ways to solve this problem?

Thanks before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `drop_duplicates`, you can simply compare the column `A` with `B`, then `mask` the values in `B` where they are equal to `A`

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['A'].eq(df['B']))
```

Alternatively you can also use boolean indexing with `loc` to mask the duplicated values

```
df.loc[df['A'].eq(df['B']), 'B'] = np.nan
```

---

```
     A    B
0  Syd  NaN
1  Aus  Del
2  Mir  Ard
3  Dol  NaN
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer, it really a very simple and minimalistic approach. Just want to make sure, after we mask the duplicated value with NaN we can use `df.fillna('',inplace=True)` to remove all the NaN. Is that right?

Comment: Glad it worked. You can mask with empty string instead of `nan`, no need to use `fillna` afterwards. Check `df.loc[df['A'].eq(df['B']), 'B'] = ''`

Comment: It works like magic! Every duplicate value now disappear. Many thanks for the answer. Let me vote your comments as the best answer. Best regards