# How to remove duplicates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have lots  of data in excel files. I would like to concatenate these datas into one excel file by removing duplicate records according to id column information.

```
df1 
   id    name   date 
0   1    cab    2017
1  11    den    2012 
2  13    ers    1998


df2 
   id    name   date 
0  11    den    2012
1  14    ces    2011 
2   4    guk    2007
```

I want to have below concantenated file finally.

```
Concat df
   id    name   date 
0   1    cab    2017
1  11    den    2012 
2  13    ers    1998
1  14    ces    2011 
2   4    guk    2007
```

I try below but it does not remove duplicates. Can anyone advise how to fix this ?

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

My concatenated data are as below. Duplicated ids are still on the file.

```
    id                  created_at          retweet_count
0   721557296757797000  2016-04-17 04:34:00 21
1   721497712726844000  2016-04-17 00:37:14 94
2   721462059515453000  2016-04-16 22:15:33 0
3   721460623285072000  2016-04-16 22:09:51 0
4   721460397241446000  2016-04-16 22:08:57 0
5   721459817651577000  2016-04-16 22:06:39 0
6   721456334894469000  2016-04-16 21:52:48 0
7   721557296757797000  2016-04-17 04:34:00 21
8   721497712726844000  2016-04-17 00:37:14 94
9   721462059515453000  2016-04-16 22:15:33 0
10  721460623285072000  2016-04-16 22:09:51 0
11  721460397241446000  2016-04-16 22:08:57 0
12  721459817651577000  2016-04-16 22:06:39 0
13  721456334894469000  2016-04-16 21:52:48 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `subset` to [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for filtering by column `id`:

```
print pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='id').reset_index(drop=True)
   id name  date
0   1  cab  2017
1  11  den  2012
2  13  ers  1998
3  14  ces  2011
4   4  guk  2007
```

EDIT:

I try your new data and for me it works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at': {0: '2016-04-17 04:34:00', 1: '2016-04-17 00:37:14', 2: '2016-04-16 22:15:33', 3: '2016-04-16 22:09:51', 4: '2016-04-16 22:08:57', 5: '2016-04-16 22:06:39', 6: '2016-04-16 21:52:48', 7: '2016-04-17 04:34:00', 8: '2016-04-17 00:37:14', 9: '2016-04-16 22:15:33', 10: '2016-04-16 22:09:51', 11: '2016-04-16 22:08:57', 12: '2016-04-16 22:06:39', 13: '2016-04-16 21:52:48'}, 'retweet_count': {0: 21, 1: 94, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 21, 8: 94, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0}, 'id': {0: 721557296757797000, 1: 721497712726844000, 2: 721462059515453000, 3: 721460623285072000, 4: 721460397241446000, 5: 721459817651577000, 6: 721456334894469000, 7: 721557296757797000, 8: 721497712726844000, 9: 721462059515453000, 10: 721460623285072000, 11: 721460397241446000, 12: 721459817651577000, 13: 721456334894469000}},
                  columns=['id','created_at','retweet_count'])
```

```
print df
                    id           created_at  retweet_count
0   721557296757797000  2016-04-17 04:34:00             21
1   721497712726844000  2016-04-17 00:37:14             94
2   721462059515453000  2016-04-16 22:15:33              0
3   721460623285072000  2016-04-16 22:09:51              0
4   721460397241446000  2016-04-16 22:08:57              0
5   721459817651577000  2016-04-16 22:06:39              0
6   721456334894469000  2016-04-16 21:52:48              0
7   721557296757797000  2016-04-17 04:34:00             21
8   721497712726844000  2016-04-17 00:37:14             94
9   721462059515453000  2016-04-16 22:15:33              0
10  721460623285072000  2016-04-16 22:09:51              0
11  721460397241446000  2016-04-16 22:08:57              0
12  721459817651577000  2016-04-16 22:06:39              0
13  721456334894469000  2016-04-16 21:52:48              0

print df.dtypes

id                int64
created_at       object
retweet_count     int64
dtype: object


print df.drop_duplicates(subset='id').reset_index(drop=True)
                   id           created_at  retweet_count
0  721557296757797000  2016-04-17 04:34:00             21
1  721497712726844000  2016-04-17 00:37:14             94
2  721462059515453000  2016-04-16 22:15:33              0
3  721460623285072000  2016-04-16 22:09:51              0
4  721460397241446000  2016-04-16 22:08:57              0
5  721459817651577000  2016-04-16 22:06:39              0
6  721456334894469000  2016-04-16 21:52:48              0
```

Comment: It still does not work for me. It still list the duplicated id columns. @jezrael

Comment: You have duplicates in `id` column? If yes, are `dtypes` same of column `id` in each Dataframe? Check it by `print df.dtypes`

Comment: yes, dtypes are the same, all datas in id column are numbers.

Comment: Hmmm, sometimes numbers can be `string` - then `dtypes` are `object`. But if `dtypes` of all columns `id` are `int`, that it is weird.

Comment: id numbers are in this format in excel file: 7.21460623285072E+017 which means 721460623285072000. How can I check dtype  of id column ?

Comment: You can check them by `print df1.id.dtypes`

Comment: it prints dtypes is int64.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe format is different - some are with `E` some not.

Comment: No jezrael, all numbers are with E format. I don' t get why it does not work.

Comment: Is possible share your data?

Comment: I have just added concatenated data into my question part. The same data were in the different files; but when I concatenated it, it does not remove duplicates.

Comment: I add my output to answer. Is your output different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109368/discussion-between-jezrael-and-behzat).

Answer (score 1):

another way :

```
df1.append(df2).groupby('id').first()
```