# pandas change a specific column value of duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Using the example here [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Lets say I don't want to drop the duplicates but change the value of the data in one of the columns in the subset.

So as per the example, if we use subset=['A','C'] to identify duplicates then I want to change row 1 column 'A' from foo to foo1.

I have a complicated way of doing this but there must be a more simple way that takes advantage of vectorization/built-in features.

**Original df:**

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 0   A
1   foo 1   A
2   foo 1   B
3   bar 1   A
```

**Desired df:**

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 0   A
1   foo1 1   A
2   foo 1   B
3   bar 1   A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cumcount` and do something like

```
>>> c = df.groupby(["A","C"]).cumcount()
>>> c = c.replace(0, '').astype(str)
>>> df["A"] += c
>>> df
      A  B  C
0   foo  0  A
1  foo1  1  A
2   foo  1  B
3   bar  1  A
```

This works because the `cumcount` gives us

```
>>> df.groupby(["A","C"]).cumcount()
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Amazing. Works great. Thank you!!