# Pandas: Find duplicates and modify them based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe and I want to find the duplicates based on Color and Price. Then change the code with the code of the most recent(based on the Date) row. I don't want any row to be deleted.
The dataframe is this:

```
id   Color   Price   Code       Date 
1   White    1.50     111   3-22-2017 12:00
2   Green    2.20     222   3-23-2017 09:55
3   Black    3.00     333   3-24-2017 11:45
4   White    1.50     111   3-23-2017 10:20
5   White    1.50     444   3-23-2017 08:15
6   Green    2.20     555   3-25-2017 07:05
```

the result should be this:

```
   id   Color   Price   Code       Date 
    1   White    1.50     111   3-22-2017 12:00
    2   Green    2.20     **555**   3-23-2017 09:55
    3   Black    3.00     333   3-24-2017 11:45
    4   White    1.50     111   3-23-2017 10:20
    5   White    1.50     **111**   3-23-2017 08:15
    6   Green    2.20     555   3-25-2017 07:05
```

I know that the answer is close to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367524/pandas-change-a-specific-column-value-of-duplicate-rows?rq=1) but the form of the date confuses me.

Comment: I think need `111` instead `444`, because more resent date is `3-23-2017 10:20` in `white, 1.5` group

Comment: @jezrael yoy are right. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and function [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
#if not datetime, convert it
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Code'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Color', 'Price'])['Code'].transform('last')
print (df)
   id  Color  Price  Code                Date
0   1  White    1.5   111 2017-03-22 12:00:00
1   2  Green    2.2   555 2017-03-23 09:55:00
2   3  Black    3.0   333 2017-03-24 11:45:00
3   4  White    1.5   111 2017-03-23 10:20:00
4   5  White    1.5   111 2017-03-23 08:15:00
5   6  Green    2.2   555 2017-03-25 07:05:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `df.groupby` followed by `dfGroupBy.transform` to pick the last value:

```
In [406]: df.Code = df.sort_values('Date')\
                      .groupby(['Color', 'Price']).Code.transform('last') # faster than lambda 

In [407]: df
Out[407]: 
   id  Color  Price  Code             Date
0   1  White    1.5   111  3-22-2017 12:00
4   5  White    1.5   111  3-23-2017 08:15
1   2  Green    2.2   555  3-23-2017 09:55
3   4  White    1.5   111  3-23-2017 10:20
2   3  Black    3.0   333  3-24-2017 11:45
5   6  Green    2.2   555  3-25-2017 07:05
```

Make sure your dataframe is sorted by `Date`, by calling `df.sort_values` first.

Also, as jezrael pointed out, I think your expected output is incorrect. To get the correct output, you must ensure that `Date` is of `pd.datetime` type. Convert it if it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is a solution that doesn't require sorting by date. 
You can get the most recent row for each color-price pair by

```
key = [df.Color, df.Price]; 
most_recent = df.groupby(key).Date.transform(max)
```

Then do

```
code = df.Code.where(df.Date == most_recent).groupby(key).transform(max)
```

Comment: I would argue passing `lambda` to `transform` isn't a good idea. This solution is around 2x faster even when the data is already sorted by date. I chose to solution such that the data wasn't sorted by date.