# Drop row from dataset if value exceeds certain character length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, that has several columns where I would like to pinpoint and extract where the value is a certain length (if it exceeds 10 characters) and to remove this row

data

```
ID             type
abccccc        22
aaaaaaaaaaa    22
b              11
```

desired

```
ID             type
abccccc        22
b              11
```

doing

```
df.drop(df.index[df['ID'] == >10
```

I am still researching this, any assistance is appreciated

Comment: Think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895061/how-to-remove-a-row-from-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-length-of-the-column-valu) is related to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[df['ID'].str.len() <= 10]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to show what row was dropped?

Comment: If you want to get the rows where the value of the ID  exceeds 10 characters, you can execute `df[df['ID'].str.len() > 10]`. Alternatively, you can add a column to your dataframe as follows  `df["long_ID"] = df['ID'].str.len() > 10`. This columns will have True values in rows with IDs exceeding 10 characters and False values in the other rows.

Comment: @Lynn: Alternatively, you can use `index.to_list()` to get the list of indices matching the condition: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-pandas/how-to-get-index-of-all-rows-whose-particular-column-satisfies-given-condition-in-pandas/