# remove duplicates from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "df" like the sample below.  I would like to use address and business_id as a unique key, and filter the dataframe so it only has unique records based on the combination of address and business_id.  Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Code:

```
print df[["address","business_id","city"]][1:3]
```

Sample Data:

```
               address             business_id       city
1       2824 Milton Rd  mLwM-h2YhXl2NCgdS84_Bw  Charlotte
2  337 Danforth Avenue  v2WhjAB3PIBA8J8VxG3wEg    Toronto
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(["address","business_id"])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score -1):

Along with removing the duplicate, you want to use df.set_index

```
df.set_index(keys=["address","business_id"])
```