# Remove duplicates of pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Trying use the DataFrame.drop_duplicates parameters but without luck as the duplicates are not being removed.

Looking to remove based on column "inc_id". If find duplicates in that column should keep only the last row.

My df is:

```
    inc_id  inc_cr_date
0   1049670 121
1   1049670 55
2   1049667 121
3   1049640 89
4   1049666 12
5   1049666 25
```

Output should be:

```
    inc_id  inc_cr_date
0   1049670 55
1   1049667 121
2   1049640 89
3   1049666 25
```

Code is:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='inc_id', keep="last")
```

Any idea what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the output you get that seems erroneous?

Comment: Actually not an error, but the df series continues with duplicates. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are just looking to [drop the original index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [11]: df.drop_duplicates(subset='inc_id', keep="last").reset_index(drop=True)
Out[11]:
    inc_id  inc_cr_date
0  1049670           55
1  1049667          121
2  1049640           89
3  1049666           25
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work as the df continues with duplicates. thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo this is running code from your example! What is it your solution does wrong? Can you include the "bad output" from your example in your question?

Comment: @Gonzalo  ,assign it back  `df=df.drop_duplicates(subset='inc_id', keep="last").reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @AndyHayden My bad, it's working your adjustment. I was looking to the wrong output (saving to csvs..)Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For dataframe df, duplicate rows can be dropped using this code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/data-set.csv')
print(df['text'])

def clean_data(dataframe):
    # Drop duplicate rows
    dataframe.drop_duplicates(subset='text', inplace=True)

clean_data(df)
print(df['text'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f.drop_duplicates(subset='inc_id', keep="last").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  It would be awesome if you could [edit] your answer and expand a bit on it, and share how your code adds to the previous answer, and helps to answer the original question. `f.drop_duplicates(subset='inc_id', keep="last").reset_index(drop=True)` does appear as part of the accepted answer.