# How to remove duplicates from Excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on excel sheet:

```
animal name    age
dog    puppy   1
dog    doggy   2
dog    snooppy 3
cat    pussy   1
pig    piggy   1
pig    cutty   2
rabit  robby   1
rabbit bunny   2
```

Here I should check if animal age is 1 should delete that row and print next row and remove duplicates if there are no duplicates, should print that row and this output should print in other excel sheet.

Can any help me out of this?

```
import 
imatplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\c_ssaiva\Desktop\sampladata.xlsx")
for index,row in data.iterrows():
print(index,row['animal'],row['name'],row['age'])
for j,row in data.iterrows():

 if a[i] == a[j]:
 if a[i] == 1
 print a[j]
 else:
 print (a[i])
 df = data
 df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\c_ssaiva\Desktop\selcol.xlsx")
```

Comment: What is yout expected output?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use `df.drop_duplicates`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas

Comment: to print next row where age != 1 , if there are duplicates

Comment: if no duplicates  print the output to aexcelsheet

Comment: output check if row 1 animal = row 2 animal , then check row 1 age = 1, then print row2 .if row1 animal != 1,then print row1

Answer (score 0):

Hej Shrvya. Pandas is awesome and can do all you are asking without loops :)
You could do that in one line

```
df = data[data['age'] != 1].drop_duplicates()
```

We have made a new df that removes all records where 'age' != 1 and then we drop duplicates :)

I am not sure what is the aim of printing values out. Why do you want to print values on screen?

Comment: but i need animal whose age = 1 when there are no duplicates

Comment: Ah! age_one = data[(data['age']==1)&(~data.duplicated())]

Comment: I need if there are no duplicates for age =1 that animal and other animals which has duplicates should remove ,where age =1 and print next age .

Comment: In above I have used two conditions, one asking for the condition that the animal has to be 1 years old and there should not be duplicates

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but if you look at the above answers, you can build your own conditions ;)

Comment: i am looking if first row age is one skip and print next row age, with same animal.if animal has no duplicates then print that row . thanks prayson daniel

Comment: Should we begin by removing dublicates, then find animals with age one, then print the next animal’s age of the same kind? Is this correct?

Comment: no  first we should check ,if age is 1 then print next animal and drop duplicates.

Comment: if no duplicates for animal with age = one then print that animal

Comment: Why are we printing those values?

Comment: in a new excelsheet

Comment: print(x) just displays the values, it is not needed to generate new file?

Comment: print(x) is not generate file.

Comment: df.to_excel(r"")  this will generate file

Comment: i need just logic how to check check the first row with second , if first row == second row if the column age =1 , if equls print second row else print firstrow

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this simple:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```