# python data science Find movies with highest female ratings

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working on an assignment for my Data Science class. I just need help getting started, as I'm having trouble understanding how to use pandas to group and selecting `DISTINCT` values.

I need to find the movies with the **HIGHEST RATINGS** by **FEMALES**, my code returns me movies with `ratings = 5`, and `gender = 'F'`, but it also repeats the same movie over and over again, since there are more than 1 users. I'm not sure how to just show movie, count of 5-star ratings, and gender = F. below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
m = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
u = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
r = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')

ur = pd.merge(u,r)
data = pd.merge(m,ur)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

top10 = df.loc[(df.gender == 'F')&(df.rating == 5)]
print(top10)
```

the data files can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w7em43m7bukvvc/movielens%20%282%29.zip?dl=0)

I just need some help getting started, theres alot more to the homework, but once I figure this out I can do the rest. Just need a jump-start. thank you very much

## **mv_id**   **title**             **genres**              **rating**    **user_id** **gender**

```
1       Toy Story (1995)   Animation|Children's|Comedy  5   1   F    
2       Jumanji (1995)     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy 5   2   F        
3       Grumpier Old Men (1995) Comedy|Romance          5   3   F            
4       Waiting to Exhale (1995)    Comedy|Drama        5   4   F        
5       Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy      5   5   F
```

Comment: Don't provide external links rather provide some sample data in text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Can you provide how your df, top10 and desired top 10 looks like ?

Comment: i've added a top 5 list above^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to do the filtering operation on as little data as possible. To select 5-star ratings of female users, there's no need for the movie metadata (movies.csv). It can be done on the `ur` data, which is easier than on the `df`.

```
# filter the data in `ur`
f_5s_ratings = ur.loc[(ur.gender == 'F')&(ur.rating == 5)]

# count rows per `movie_id`
abs_num_f_5s_ratings = f_5s_ratings.groupby("movie_id").size()
```

In `abs_num_f_5s_ratings` you now have a DataFrame counting the total number of 5-star ratings by female users per movie_id:

```
movie_id
1       253
2        15
3        14
...
```

If you join that data on the key `movie_id` with `m` as a new column (I'll leave it as an exercise to you), you can then sort by this value to get your top 10 movies with absolute number of 5-star ratings by females.