# Manipulating duplicate rows across a subset of columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"user":[11,11,11,21,21,21,21,21,32,32], 
               "event":[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0], 
               "datetime":['05:29:54','05:32:04','05:32:08',
                           '15:35:26','15:36:07','15:36:16','15:36:50','15:36:54',
                           '09:29:12', '09:29:25'] })
```

[image]

I would like to handle the repetitive lines across the first column (user) to reach the following.

[image]

In this case, we replace the 'event' column with the maximum value related in the 'user' column (for example for user=11, the maximum value for event is 1). And the third column is replaced by the average of the datetime.

P.S. It has been already discussed about dropping the repetitive rows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas), however, I do not want to drop rows blindly. Especially when I am dealing with a dataframe with a lot of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `groupby` and `aggregate`

```
df.groupby('user').agg({'event': 'max', 
                        'datetime': lambda s: pd.to_timedelta(s).mean()})
```

If you want, you can also just change your `datetime` column first to `timedelta` using `pd.to_timedelta` and just take the `mean` in the `agg`

You can use `str` to represent the way you intend

```
df.groupby('user').agg({'event': 'max', 
                        'datetime': lambda s: str(pd.to_timedelta(s).mean().to_pytimedelta())})
```

Comment: Thanks @RafaelC for the quick answer. I liked the way that you did average on the datetime column. However, if I have the datetime columns as e.g., '2018-09-01 05:29:54', then the average method return funny result for the day-month-year! although it is correct for the hour-min-sec as you have shown it. Do you have any comment on it?

Comment: @AminKiany You can just convert back to python time delta and use `str` on it. Will edit in a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `datetime`s to native integers and aggregate `mean`, last convert back and for `HH:MM:SS` strings use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).astype(np.int64)

df1 = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).agg({'event':'max', 'datetime':'mean'})
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df1)
   user  event  datetime
0    11      1  05:31:22
1    21      1  15:36:18
2    32      0  09:29:18
```

Comment: Thanks! for the quick reply :)