# Removing duplicates with three conditions, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     reference | topcredit | currentbalance | creditlimit
  1      1      |    50     |       20       |      70
  2      1      |    30     |       28       |      50
  3      1      |    50     |       20       |      70
  4      1      |    81     |       32       |      100
  5      2      |    70     |        0       |      56
  6      2      |    50     |       20       |      70
  7      2      |   100     |        0       |      150
  8      3      |    85     |       85       |      95
  9      3      |    85     |       85       |      95
```

And so on...

I want to drop duplicates based on the 'reference' only those that have the same topcredit, currentbalance and creditlimit.

In the reference 1 I have two that have the same numbers in the three columns in line 1 and 3, but also in reference 2, line 6 I would like to keep 1 of reference 1 and also line 6 of reference 2. In reference 3 both lines have the same information too.

The expected output is:

```
 reference | topcredit | currentbalance | creditlimit
    1      |    50     |       20       |      70
    1      |    30     |       28       |      50
    1      |    81     |       32       |      100
    2      |    70     |       24       |      56
    2      |    50     |       20       |      70
    2      |   100     |       80       |      150
    3      |    85     |       85       |      95
```

I would apreciate the help, I've been searching how to do it for a while.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()`, or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you do it based on 3 conditions: topcredit, currentbalance and creditlimit being the same for two rows in each reference? If I drop duplicates on  current balance or any other column reference 2 would've been dropped too.

Comment: You drop duplicates on **all** columns (i.e. just specify nothing), so that a row gets removed only if the same reference has the same topcredit and currentbalance and creditlimit.

Comment: wow, thanks! I was thinking of very complicated solutions that I didn't think of such simple one. Thanks! @ALollz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)