# Pandas: drop row if one column duplicate and another column distinct

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I want to drop rows in a pandas dataframe where value in one column A is duplicate and value in some other column B is not a duplicate given A. An illustrative example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'bat'],
                   'B': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z'],
                   'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
```

[image]

The desired output has Row 3 dropped as "cat" is duplicate and "z" is distinct in "cat" rows:

[image]

`df.drop_duplicates('A')` removes Rows 2 and 3, and `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'])` removes Row 2; neither is what I am looking for here  [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
df[(~df.duplicated('A')) | df.duplicated(['A','B'])]
```

Output:

```
     A  B   C
0  cat  x  10
1  dog  y  20
2  bat  z  30
3  cat  x  40
```

Comment: It seems to work. I try it on the original dataset too to see it it works there too. Thanks! (also, I had a typo in the question code that I just corrected)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `transform`

```
df[df.B==df.groupby('A').B.transform('first')]
Out[11]: 
     A  B   C
0  cat  x  10
1  dog  y  20
2  cat  x  30
4  bat  z  50
```