# Pandas drop.duplicate function doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, replicate

I am currently working on different data frames that I should merge. One of my data frame has many duplicates on my key of merge variable, so I used `drop.duplicate` to remove them.
Later checked the shape of my data frame before (it had 531 rows) and after (167 rows). So I supposed it worked!
But by using `value.counts[key of merge]`, it doesn't return `1` for each entry of my key of merge variable. How could I explain this, and correct it?

For better understanding, here is my code :

```
df_stores.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Store ID', keep = 'first' )

df_stores['Store ID'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)
```

Comment: Could you share your code please? We have to blind guess if you don't.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We ask that you provide a [mcve] for your issue, including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far

Comment: drop.duplicates will remove the rows if all the columns are duplicating. Check in the cases where Count > 1 if any one data point is different. I am guessing!!!

Comment: I agree with @Vikika you are probably missing the `susbet` parameter, but I won't provide an answer until I can see the code.

Comment: Sorry, here is my code : df_stores.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Store ID', keep = 'first' )

df_stores['Store ID'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)

Comment: Did you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas. Also try to provide a sample dataset in these cases.

Possible duplicate question

Comment: And this is what value.counts returns : 
1400     4
1401     4
1402     4
1403     4
1404     4
        ..
75001    4
75002    4
75003    4
75016    1
75098    2
Name: Store ID, Length: 167, dtype: int64

Comment: @RahulKhanna Thank you ! After reading : indeed, I need to keep one of my duplicate (the first one). I don't understand the inplace parameter

Comment: Inplace parameter is used when you want to persist your changes to the same dataframe as original. When you use this param, the original dataframe will be overwritten by the operation you have performed.

Comment: @RahulKhanna I manage to fix my problem, by adding the parameter inplace = True. I understand inplace now and its importance thanks to your answer ! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so it is easilty accessible for others. I am writing the answer There are two ways:

**1.** 
`df_stores.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Store ID', keep = 'first', inplace= True)`

Note: Do not use it everywhere as it throws warning in some cases

**2.**
`df_stores = df_stores.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Store ID', keep = 'first')`

Comment: Thank you ! It is the first time I share a question and I need to get used of the do's of the website !