# Pandas - Validate & Upload Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am planning on using panda dataframes to read a large CSV file and publish this data into postgresql db. I'll be performing this process everyday and want to load only the changes to the database. Would panda dataframes be able to identify the delta between what is present in the table vs what is present in the dataframe and proceed with the data upload?

Comment: Seems doable yes, sure. Depends on volumes though, but I could easily imagine you load all your `.csv` using an iterator, generate hashes of every row. Then compare these hashes with hashes of your DB rows.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by removing duplicate rows. But this will take more time since the database is growing every day. Join database and CSV file and don't keep common rows.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud & Hariprasad. The largest file that I have is 1 GB.