# Finding the top 3 locations with most snow and store it

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code right now

```
df = df2016.nlargest(3,['Snow Mean'])
df.to_csv('top3.csv')
```

However, I am getting duplicated locations with this code, because all my top snow is from the same location, this code is only giving me one location three times.

[image]

Here is my data. On the image, the second column is the location and the last column is snow. I want my code to store Grand Rapids 2.5 ENE, and Grand Rapids 4.6 ESE as top 2 but my code is storing all top 3's the same location. I also tried dropping duplicates but it didn't work. How can I find the top 3 without duplicates?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is? _I also tried dropping duplicates but it didn't work._ We need a [mcve], then. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but my question was already solved and I did flag an answer.

Comment: That doesn’t mean the question’s life is over though, much to the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2016.sort_values('Snow Mean', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='Location Column', keep='first').head(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas.Dataframe.drop_duplicates() should work fine. You should just use only the second and the last column before you use this function because the 3d(third) column with the data has unique values.

```
    df = df2016['column2', 'column5'].drop_duplicates.nlargest(3, ['Snow Mean'])
    df.to_csv('top3.csv')
```

or

```
    df = df2016.iloc[:, [1, 5]].drop_duplicates.nlargest(3, ['Snow Mean'])
    df.to_csv('top3.csv')
```

This should work as you want until there are no unique values in last column with snow data in the same region.