# Pandas dataframe - duplicates in data but dups don't reside in same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where there are duplicate rows in aggregate but in this form:

```
timestamp   animal_1  animal_2  
2020-06-28  14:28:57  dog fox    
2020-06-28  14:28:57  fox dog   
2020-06-29  18:28:57  dog fox   
2020-06-29  18:28:57  fox dog   
2020-06-30  17:35:57  dog fox   
2020-06-30  17:35:57  fox dog
```

I only want to keep the rows that have a unique timestamp followed by a single combination of both animals. From the above df I would only want to return the following:

```
timestamp   animal_1  animal_2   
2020-06-28  14:28:57  dog fox    
2020-06-29  18:28:57  fox dog  
2020-06-30  17:35:57  dog fox
```

What matters is that I return the number of times these 2 animals have interacted.

I have tried multiple sorting, grouping options using pandas but have had no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need sort the column animals , the `drop_duplicates`

```
df[['animal_1', 'animal_2']]=np.sort(df[['animal_1', 'animal_2']].values, axis=1)
df=df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: thanks for the code, I tested it and it works perfectly.  Appreciate the help.