# how to group data in a column based on indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am a newbie, slowly learning... i have a unique dataframe as shown below:

```
               time
index
 1            8:51 am 
 1            8:51 am
 1            8:51 am
 2            8:52 am
 2            8:52 am
 3            8:53 am
 3            8:53 am
 3            8:53 am
```

i want to be able to combine the dataframe and input the index in one row only as shown below:

```
                time
index
 1            8:51 am 
 2            8:52 am
 3            8:53 am
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).head(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks unique there, that just seems to be whole duplicate rows (unless timestamps can be different for same index number)

Df.drop_duplicates function is what you’re looking for.

You can also use this function even if timestamp can be different by just running it over a selected column( index) and argument “first” or “last” will keep first or last of those timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="time",   keep = False, inplace = True)
```

This should return only the rows of the dataframe containing unique values in the subset column mentioned.