# How can I remove duplicate raws at pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I using pandas for deep learning.
I have a data like this.

```
a   b   c  
0   [1] [1,2]  
1   [2] [3,4]  
0   [3] [5,6]   
1   [1] [1,2]  
1   [2] [3,4]
```

I want to remove just thing that not duplicate `a` columns & duplciate `b`,`c` columns.
Like this.

```
a   b   c  
1   [2] [3,4]  
0   [3] [5,6]     
1   [2] [3,4]
```

I used `drop_duplicate(subset['b','c'], keep=False]`
But result isn't that I want.

```
a   b   c  
0   [3] [5,6]
```

How can I remove this?
It's different remove all duplicate.
I want to remove just "same 2 columns but different 1 columns".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Try `keep = True`

Comment: No I want to remove all "not duplicate `a` columns & duplciate `b`,`c` columns."  If I use `keep = True` data remove one raw & remain one raw.  I want to remove all.

Comment: You should include `a` in your `drop_duplicate`

Comment: You mean `drop_duplicate(subset['a', 'b', 'c'], keep=False)` or I just must to remove all duplciates?