# Pandas: how to only keep rows that are unique?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
    x   
1   paris   
2   paris  
3   lyon  
4   lyon   
5   toulouse
```

I would like to only keep not duplicated rows, for exemple above I would like to only keep the row 'toulouse'.

I tried drop duplicates pandas function but doesn't work:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x'], inplace=True)
```

Expected output:

```
      x   
 5 toulouse
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

> keep{‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
> Determines which duplicates (if any) to keep. - first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence. - last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence. - False : Drop all duplicates.

It says , `keep=False` would drop all duplicates. So you can do:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x'], keep=False,inplace=True)
```

Related Post:
[Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)