# Remove duplicate rows from dataframe if

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I'm working with a pandas dataframe and I want to remove duplicate rows based on the column ID value, but among the duplicate rows, I want to keep the row if the Value column has a value.

I know of

> .drop_duplicates(subset="ID", keep="first")

, but that would keep duplicate rows if the Value cells are different.

Input Table:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | qwer |
| B | asdf |
| A |  |
| C |  |

Output Table:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | qwer |
| B | asdf |
| C |  |

Thanks

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','qwer'])`?

Comment: @wwnde I can't do that for every row though...:/

Comment: `@wwnde I can't do that for every row though...:/` why cant you do it that way? Is there something I missed

Comment: @wwnde wouldn't that only apply to the first row of my example Input Table? What about other rows where there's duplicate ID but not duplicate Value?

Comment: Edits after your question edit `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Value'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @wwnde no, `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Value'])` would keep both the first row and the last row of the Input Table, no?

Comment: `df1=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Value'])` or `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Value'], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is from your logic:

```
# mark the duplicated rows
duplicated = df['ID'].duplicated()

# non-nan rows
# consider `.ne('')` if you are searching for blank value
not_empty = df['Value'].notna()

# keep rows that are not duplicated or non-nan
# that is to remove those that are **both** duplicates and has empty value
df[(~duplicated) | not_empty]
```