# Remove rows if value exists in other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I Have Two Dataframes `df` and `ds`
import pandas as pd

```
ds = pd.DataFrame({'Price': {0: 1200, 1: 1400, 2: 1500,
                                 3: 1800},
                   'Time(s)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 600,
                                 3: 500},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03',
                          3: 'a04'}})

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': {0: 1200, 1: 1500, 2: 1450,
                                 3: 1800, 4: 1200},
                   'Time(s)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 500,
                                 3: 500, 4: 500},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03',
                          3: 'a04', 4: 'a05 '}})
```

**ds** Output:

```
   Price        Time(s)     id   
   1200         500         a01 
   1400         500         a02
   1500         600         a03
   1800         500         a04
```

**df** Output:

```
   Price        Time(s)     id  
   1200         500         a01 
   1500         500         a03
   1450         500         a02
   1800         500         a04
   1200         500         a05
```

`Desired Output:` `df1:`

```
   Price        Time(s)     id  
   1200         500         a05
```

I want to compare them, anf if there same values in `id` column in both datframes drop them, and outcome save into new dataframe `df1`, i tried to:

`df1 = pd.concat([ds,df])` and

`df1.drop_duplicates(subset='id',keep='last')`
But The Values were the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: use `keep=False` to remove all duplicates

Comment: @Nick Nope, that's not mine

Comment: @Nick keep=false not helping  still giving me full dataframe after pd.concat()

Comment: `False` is spelt with a capital letter. `df1.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) via [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) is also an option:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = pd.DataFrame({'Price': {0: 1200, 1: 1400, 2: 1500,
                             3: 1800},
                   'Time(s)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 600,
                               3: 500},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03',
                          3: 'a04'}})

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': {0: 1200, 1: 1500, 2: 1450,
                             3: 1800, 4: 1200},
                   'Time(s)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 500,
                               3: 500, 4: 500},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03',
                          3: 'a04', 4: 'a05 '}})

out = df.loc[np.where(df['id'].isin(ds['id']), False, True)]

# For Display
print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

```
Price  Time(s)   id
 1200      500  a05
```

Answer (score 2):

`keep=False` should do the trick.
P.S It must be passed as bool and not string.

```
pd.concat([df, ds]).drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Price   Time(s) id
0   1200    500     a05
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
ds.merge(df, on='id', how='outer', indicator=True, suffixes=('_xxx',''))
  .query('_merge!="both"')[df.columns]
```

[image]

The merge simulates SQL full outer join. `indicator=True` adds `_merge` column that shows `left_only, right_only or both`, in this case anything that is not both is solution, but in general you can be more specific with subsequent query filter.

Other suggestions of using `pd.concat` will work in some cases, but they are not generic enough in my opinion. Those solution could include unique records from both dataframes, but in this case you asked from the other one.

Answer (score 1):

df1 = pd.merge(df, ds, how='outer',on="id", indicator='common')

df1 = df1.loc[df1['common'] != 'both']

df1