# Pandas Dataframe remove rows depending on two columns with equal values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

basically i have a dataframe where is a lot of columns, but the main are ITEM_ID and PRICE.

For example:

```
ID  ITEM_ID  ITEM     PRICE
1      1      potato    20
2      1      potato    20
3      1      potato    25
4      2      tomato    50
5      2      tomato    55
```

And I want to delete the rows where ITEM_ID and PRICE are equal, so the output will be this:

```
ID  ITEM_ID  ITEM     PRICE
1      1      potato    20
2      1      potato    25
3      2      tomato    50
4      2      tomato    55
```

I am counting average price using

```
df['AVG'] = df.groupby('ITEM_ID')['PRICE'].transform('mean')
```

But I realised, that I am counting using the duplicate values, so the average is not right.

Can anybody help?

EDIT:

After trying suggested

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id', 'price'])
```

the data are still there, even keep=False wont do nothing.

Comment: looks like you want to drop duplicates?``df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id', 'price'])``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, the rows are still there.

Comment: Now its working, have to add inplace=True

Comment: Can you add the solution as answer and mark it accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to this problem is:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id', 'price'], inplace=True)
```