# Drop rows where one column has specific value and other columns are null?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df like this (a small sample):

| time | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0500 | unit1 | 1 | nan |
| 0500 | unit1 | nan | 1 |
| 0500 | unit1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0500 | unit2 | 1 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | 1 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | nan | 1 |
| 0500 | unit3 | 1 | 1 |

What I want is this:

| time | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0500 | unit1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0500 | unit2 | 1 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | 1 | 1 |

I have a list of duplicate values,
`duplicates = ['unit1', 'unit3']`

What I attempted is this:

```
for unit in duplicates:
        temp_df = df.loc[df['name'] == unit].dropna()
        update_df = update_df.append(temp_df)
```

but as I iterate, it's appending the dropped nan values back into the data-frame for other duplicate units. How else can I do this with a data-frame? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @sushanth I don't believe so. The columns I need to drop have nans, not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try:

Firstly sort values by using `sort_values()` and after that store your condition in a variable so here the condition gives a boolean Series so after that pass that boolean Series to the dataframe and filter out rows

```
df=df.sort_values(['name','val1','val2'])
m=~((df.duplicated(subset=['name'])) & (df['name'].isin(duplicates)))
#Finally:
out=df[m]
#OR
out=df.loc[m]
```

output of `out`:

```
   time     name    val1    val2
2   500     unit1   1.0     1.0
3   500     unit2   1.0     NaN
6   500     unit3   1.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! however, when I run this, I only get rows at index 2 and 6, and I lose the row at index 3

Comment: @pariskey since you run your for loop so maybe that deleted the index 3 so kindly check your dataframe again......it's working completely fine on my side and giving me the rows of index 2,3 and 6...so can you pls recheck?