# Pandas drop_duplicates in any one columns and also in other csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

> **P.S. NOT JUST "Fruit" repeat I want "ref" repeated also drop it!!!**
> Thanks ALL!!

Q1:
Can pandas drop duplicates if any one cell is duplicated (all data from csv)

df1 read csv:

Fruit   ref

Banana  123

Banana  456

Apple   789

Apple   456

apricot 123

Orange  999

===============

I want:

Fruit   ref

Banana  123

Apple   789

Orange  999

i.e If duplicated on Fruit OR duplicated on ref then remove whole row, not matter which columns repeated, just keep the first

Q2:
Another question is similar but in anther csv

df2 read csv:

Fruit   ref

Banana  8778

Apple   7899

Mango   999

Grapes  8778

Pear    5465

Cherry  7445

Mango   5465

===========

I want:

Fruit   ref

Pear    5465

Cherry  894

Similar, I want drop duplicated not matter which columns repeated, just keep the first

Banana, Apple is repeated in df1 so drop it

999 also repeated in df1 so drop it

5465 is repeated in df2(same df) so drop it

Thus, just keep Pear 5465 and Cherry 894

Q3:
I have many csv data is similar, how can I remove all if repeated in COL(Fruit) or COL(ref)? or it must concat or merge to one csv then use drop_duplicates?

Sorry, my English not good and difficult to explain what I want, how you know what I want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first chain conditions for both columns:

```
df = df1[~df1['Fruit'].duplicated() & ~df1['ref'].duplicated()]
print (df)
    Fruit  ref
0  Banana  123
2   Apple  789
5  Orange  999
```

For second first join both DataFrames and remove duplicates same way, for values from `df2` only use inner join by `df2`:

```
df12 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df12[~df12['Fruit'].duplicated() & ~df12['ref'].duplicated()].merge(df2)
print (df)
    Fruit   ref
0    Pear  5465
1  Cherry  7445
```

Comment: Thanks it's work and that's I want~

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit' : ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apricot', 'Orange'],
    'ref' : [123, 456, 789, 456, 123, 999]
})

    Fruit   ref
0   Banana  123
1   Banana  456
2   Apple   789
3   Apple   456
4   Apricot 123
5   Orange  999
```

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Fruit"]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] == 1)
df2 = df.groupby(["ref"]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] == 1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
    Fruit   ref
4   Apricot 123
5   Orange  999
2   Apple   789
```

Also check this post to know more. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: NOT just Fruit!!! Is BOTH Fruit or ref repeated also drop it!!!

Comment: You can add column names in subset array.

Comment: It just remove both Fruit AND ref repeat. I Want  Fruit **OR** ref repeat

Answer (score -1):

just a hack,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data=[['banana',123],['banana',456],['apple',789],['apricot',123],['orange','999']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['fruit','ref'])
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['fruit'])
     fruit  ref
0   banana  123
2    apple  789
3  apricot  123
4   orange  999
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['fruit'])).drop_duplicates(subset=['ref'])
    fruit  ref
0  banana  123
2   apple  789
4  orange  999
```

[click here for snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNEVg.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32469454)

Comment: hey this is is only for the image that i was trying to paste, since stackoverflow wont allow me to  paste the image directly it generated a link

Comment: **NOTE**: As of Revision 3 (which added the code block from the image) the answer is **NOT** a link only answer

Comment: Thanks. But I can't make it to useful