# Best way to remove dataframe columns where every value is the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, read-csv

Let's say I have a DataFrame with multiple columns where the values are all the same e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['Texas','Texas','Texas','Texas'], 'County':['Harris','Harris','Harris','Harris'], 'Building':[1,2,3,4], 'Budget':[7328,3290,8342,4290]})`

I want to write a function that simply scans the df and drops the columns where all values are the same.

I have come up with the below which also returns a separate Series `x` of the removed columns and their unique value.

I am new to coding and want to understand if there is a simpler way

```
def drop_monocols(df):              #takes df
    x = dict()
    n = 0
    while n < df.shape[1]:
        if df.iloc[:,n].nunique()==1:                   #finds columns where all values same
            x[df.columns[n]] = df.iloc[0,n]             #adds to dict colname:value
            df = df.drop(df.columns[n], axis=1)         #drops useless col from df
        else:
            n +=1
        x = pd.Series(x)
    return x, df                                        #returns useless col:value series and cleaned df
```

I am new to coding and want to understand if there is a simpler way. Can I use a `for` loop with columns instead of `while`? and is it possible to use .apply here instead of calling a function with df as the arg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare to the first row and see if [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) rows are the same to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[:, ~df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all()]
```

Variant, keep if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) value is different:

```
out = df.loc[:, df.ne(df.iloc[0]).any()]
```

Or, with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) if you don't have NaNs (or want to ignore NaNs):

```
out = df.loc[:, df.nunique().gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
   Building  Budget
0         1    7328
1         2    3290
2         3    8342
3         4    4290
```